# Is it good option to host Rhohecode on Amazon EC2

Tags: web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, rhodecode

I am thinking of hosting Rhodecode for my version control of all my codes on Amazon EC2. Is that the good idea.

if that works i may also host Confluence on there as well

How much resources will it consume.

I am not able to calculate the CPUS thing. Dont know how that works

If i will only be pushing code one per day . do my cpu will be billed for 1 hour for month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RhodeCode is hungry for ressources since it’s really doing a lot of heavy work. EC2 I would not recommend for this since you will need to order at least a large instance which costs est. $175 per month!

Also other cloud providers are not really cheaper and you don’t even have a highly available setup, yet. For a professional setup you would need to budget at least $300-$400 per month on dedicated hardware.

The most cost-efficient and quick solution would be to use the new Hosted RhodeCode service at [rhodecode.com](https://rhodecode.com).

Currently the site is in private beta but you can request an invite and try it out for free. After private beta, the first users will be free of charge and any further user will cost a low USD amount per month.

Disclaimer: I am CEO at RhodeCode and my co-founder Marcin is the creator of RhodeCode SCM. You can contact me at anytime for any question through Twitter [@RhodeCode](https://twitter.com/rhodecode) or email (support @ ourdomain).

Comment: thanks . i have request for private beta one month ago but still could not get it. Any idea how much time it can take to give private beta

Comment: Today we send out the first private beta invitations. Please email me the address with which you requested the invite. I set you on priority.

Comment: Thanks , i got the invite. Is there any way i can setup the public key for pushing through ssh. currently when i (gnome-ssh-askpass:20736): `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display try to push i asks for password in gnome terminal and give error `

Comment: Great that you got the invite! SSH is currently not supported, just HTTPS.